# How to send HID commands and read HID data from Linux Kernel Module?

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, hid, ioctl

I'm building a Linux kernel module that needs to read an HID device, to send data to a hypervisor using RPC communication. These assumptions are necessary, as I'm working in embedded Linux and the SoC I'm developing for, requires a kernel module to send this type of data and send back data through registered callbacks.

I know that there are libraries such as `libusb` / `hidapi` that can simply send a HID command and read HID data from userspace, like this:

```sh
hidapitester --vidpid 2752:0012 -l 8 --open --send-output 0x03,0x53,0x02,0x58  --read-input
```

Where an ID will point to the device, and we can send and read bytes according to the manufacturer spec. We can also do this writing a program using their library functions, which ultimately are based on HIDRAW.

The issue is, these are libraries that work on userspace, but compiling a kernel module with userspace functions is not possible, thus these libraries won't work. HIDRAW relies mostly on IOCTL so using the `ioctl()` calls was tried but not successful either.

How to write and read to an HID device that I know the ID of from a Linux kernel module?

I've tried using `hidapi` and `hidraw` functions or just the direct `ioctl()` call from the kernel module but I get:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'ioctl'
```

or the equivalent with the library functions and after some research I realized these are userspace functions.

Comment: Have you seen `hid-replay` tool? https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libevdev/hid-tools

Comment: From what I understand in this repo, it also works from userspace? Seems insteresting though, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes, with a help of the **existing** kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to send an HID report/command with a kernel module.

To do so one has to create a module (read about the Linux kernel module structure if you are not familiar) and use the `struct hid_driver`. Here is necessary to register some functions that will be called once our driver is recognized as the appropriate one for a given device:

```c
static struct hid_driver my_hid_driver = {
    .name = "my-hid-receiver",
    .id_table = my_id_table,
    .probe = my_probe_function,
    .remove = my_remove_function,
    .raw_event = my_raw_event
};
```

To make our driver be called when an HID device is connected, we use the `id_table` like this:

```c
static const struct hid_device_id my_id_table[] = {
    { HID_DEVICE(HID_BUS_ANY, HID_GROUP_ANY, <ID OF THE VENDOR>, <ID OF THE PRODUCT>) },
    {}
};
```

Where `ID OF THE VENDOR` and `ID OF THE PRODUCT` can be replaced for the hex values of vendor and product. These can be read manually once using `lsusb` or `usb-devices` in userspace. Documentation of other drivers doing more specificity to select a device, or use a single module to target different types of devices is available at *drivers/hid/* in the Linux kernel source tree.

After that, the `->probe()` function will be a good starting point as this is called when the driver is first assigned to a device. We get the `hid_device` as an argument when the device is connected and the function is called. Inside we should call some necessary functions like `hid_parse()`, `hid_hw_start()` and `hid_hw_open()`, then we are ready to send a report.

Here we can use `hid_hw_request()`, a function from `hid-core`, for this purpose.

If we want to send 5 bytes of the following data `[0x01,0xff,0x01,0x33,0x0f]` we can do it like this:

```c
struct hid_report *report;
struct hid_report_enum *output_report_enum;

output_report_enum = &hdev->report_enum[HID_OUTPUT_REPORT]; // Getting the report from the hid_device hdev
report = output_report_enum->report_id_hash[<ID>]; // hid_device hdev is passed to probe as argument

report->field[0]->value[0] = 0x01; // Actual data to be sent to the device
report->field[0]->value[1] = 0xFF;
report->field[0]->value[2] = 0x01;
report->field[0]->value[3] = 0x33;
report->field[0]->value[4] = 0x0F;

hid_hw_request(hdev, report, HID_REQ_SET_REPORT); // request to set the data
```

Keep in mind that ID and field are specific to how your HID device works, I just used the simplest configuration here.

If we want to do a reading, we can use `HID_INPUT_REPORT` for the enum and `HID_REQ_GET_REPORT` for the argument `hid_hw_request()`.

We can take a look at the documentation in *include/linux/hid.h*, `hid-core` and *drivers/hid/* inside the Linux kernel source tree, to find practical examples as well as the different exposed functions to use the HID layers.

Also https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/hid/hid-transport.html can be useful if one is doing more low level operations.