# LinuxMint 21.3 HID read into LibreCalc - Multiple readers and Identification of them

Tags: rfid

With multiple rfid readers all the same vid pid and no id available, is it possible to add a suffix/prefix to the tag read into LibreCalc.  Currently all tag reads go into the same column in LibreCalc. Would need to be a reference to the USB hub port that the reader currently passing data is on.

Which is the best way to achieve

Thanks

Charles

Looked at previous discussion here:

[How to send HID commands and read HID data from Linux Kernel Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77878088/how-to-send-hid-commands-and-read-hid-data-from-linux-kernel-module)